# How to figure out the structure of a large JSON file with Node?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So, I want to dig into a large JSON file so I can loop through all of the properties in a certain subsection and convert the variables there from strings to numbers.

The problem is that the JSON is so large that I can't just open it in atom and look at it, nor can I parse it and console.log it in order to see which variables I want to access.

What's the best strategy for getting the overall structure of the JSON? Ideally I'd like to see something like

```
{
"features": ...,
"properties": [...],
"etc":...
}
```

Without it going too deep.

Comment: If it's too big to load into node.js all at once and then parse, then you will have to write your own custom parser that works through it a bit at a time, understanding it as it goes and not keeping everything in memory.  Depending upon how the JSON is structured, you might be able to write a utility that will split it into smaller pieces of legal JSON.

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question (I don't see you marked it as correct), or are you looking for other answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const file = fs.readFileSync('path/to/json/file.json')
const parsed = JSON.parse(file)
console.log(Object.keys(parsed))
```

This will give you the keys at the top level, as you mentioned that you wanted to see the shallow structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, my terminal seems to crash when I attempt this method (seemingly because the file is too large)

Comment: hmm. I don't see anywhere OP said in the original question that it is too large to load into Node

Comment: updated answer to use `readFileSync` instead of `readFile`, which does something different. can you try it again, @yoursweater?